# Is there a way to link a specific method to a Route in ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack

## The Problem

I'm aware of the basic way to create a route/endpoint in ServiceStack using methods with names like "Get", "Post", "Any", etc inside a service but in the particular case that I'm trying to work with I have an existing service (which I can make an IService via inheritance) that can not be retrofitted w/ServiceStack attributes and currently uses DTOs for the requests and responses.

This service contains many functions that I do not want to manually mask (as this is a pass-through layer) but otherwise already conform to ServiceStack's requirements. What I'm wondering is if there's a way to manually create these routes in a way that would work like I've mocked up [here](https://gist.github.com/btjake/7879305). My existing functions and DTOs already contain the information I would need to define the routes so if this approach is possible it would only require me to enumerate them at initialization time as opposed to generating the services layer manually.

I noticed there is an extension method on Routes.Add that takes an Expression of type Expression> but I was not able to get that working because I believe the underlying code makes assumptions about the type of Expression generated (LambdaExpression vs MemberExpression or something like that). I also may be barking up the wrong tree if that's not the intended purpose of that function but I can not find documentation anywhere on how that variant is supposed to work.

## Why?

I'm not sure this is necessary but to shed some light on why I want to do this as opposed to retrofitting my existing layers: The current code is also used outside of a web service context and is consumed by other code internally. Retrofitting ServiceStack in to this layer would make every place that consumes it require ServiceStack's assemblies and be aware of the web service which is a concern I want separated from the lower code. We were previously using MVC/WCF to accomplish this goal but we want some of the features available from ServiceStack.

the current architecture looks like this:
data -> DAL -> discrete business logic -> composition -> web service

Hopefully that makes enough sense and I'm not being obtuse. If you would like any more details about what I want to do or why I'll try to update this post as soon as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: You can propose feature requests on [ServiceStack's user voice](http://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests) but un-necessary delegation like this is not something we see any value in. ServiceStack's service layer should be the outer-most layer which is what realizes the external-facing Service contract, this just creates un-necessary confusion which doesn't add much value over the explicit, intuitive and debuggable alternative that currently exists.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While I understand your position I'm still interested in pursuing it. If you wouldn't mind, I'm interested in where in the code to look at where that delegation occurs (and possibly extending it). Also, if you know of any documentation about that Expression parameter I'd love to see it. Thanks again for responding.

Comment: There's a fair bit of prep work that happens before to prep the caches, but you can put a [break-point here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Host/ServiceExec.cs#L168) where the verb is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

You might use the [fallback route](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing) in order to provide your own routing mechanism.

Then you get the request.Path property and route using your own mapping of path:Function which can be stored in a simple dictionary.

Anyway, if you go this path I don't see much benefit in using servicestack. It seems you just need an http handler that routes requests to existing services.